# python requests: url with another sub-requests

Tags: python, url, python-requests

When I execute **manually** this URL in my webbrowser I see in my network console that three other requests will be executed. it works.

**call:** www.my.url/publish_something

- get this cmd
- get that cmd
- post that...

How can I do it in Python requests?
That I only call once the "main"-URL including all sub-requests like my webbrowser.

```
> publish_url = "www.my.url/publish_something" r =
> self.session.get(publish_url, verify=False, params=p)
```

it seems, when I call this url with python requests-module, he does not execute the sub-requests.

Comment: I do not really know how to do that with requests, but if you care more about the result than knowing how to do it with `requests`, I'd suggest having a look at `selenium` which will handle the requests through a web browser and will execute the other requests

Comment: I believe you are opening a regular HTML page. Your browser will usually just send extra requests based on the HTML. Python however doesn't need to. It will just get the response. You can send the requests based on the links in the page.

Comment: You'll have to parse the HTML, extract all these links and retrieve them manually. You should also enable redirects.

Answer (score 0):

When you open an url in your browser, the browser 
- issues a GET request to that url
- parse the content
- issues GET  requests for each image tag and for each script, style etc tags mentionning an external source, 
- executes the scripts, which may lead to more sub requests and DOM modifications,
- and finally render the final DOM.

When you send a GET request with Python (with python-rquests, the urllib module or whatever), on the first of the above stages is performed, so if you want more you'll have to do it by yourself (parsing the content, retrieving images etc etc).

Or you can use a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).